# Markers on responsive map

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div that contains a map for a vitual city.
I need to place some pins or markers in it, but my problem is that the pins change location based on window width.

How can fix it so no matter what browser size used, the **pins are located at the same place on the map**?

```
<div class="MapContainer">
    <a href="http://www.google.dk" style="position: absolute; top: 240px; left: 650px;">
        <img class="pin" src="~/Content/1453392082_map_pin_fill.png" data-val-text="Bageri" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.dk" style="position: absolute; top: 258px; left: 670px;">
        <img class="pin" src="~/Content/1453392082_map_pin_fill.png" data-val-text="Rådhus" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.dk" style="position: absolute; top: 258px; left: 670px;">
        <img class="pin" src="~/Content/1453392082_map_pin_fill.png" data-val-text="Nærbrugs" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.dk" style="position: absolute; top: 258px; left: 670px;">
        <img class="pin" src="~/Content/1453392082_map_pin_fill.png" data-val-text="Ejendomshandel" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.dk" style="position: absolute; top: 258px; left: 670px;">
        <img class="pin" src="~/Content/1453392082_map_pin_fill.png" data-val-text="Avis" />
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
.MapContainer {
    background-image: url('../Content/bastumhuhej2.png');
    position: relative;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Use `%` values for the `top` and `left` properties.

Comment: have you tried to define top and left properties with relative units (e.g. `%`)?

Comment: With % i can still see small movements in the positions of the pins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using an image tag rather than a background-image for the map. This way, the container can adapt its size according to the map.

Then, you can position the markers absolutely with top and left percent values. This will allow the **markers to move with the map** and stay in the same position like in the following example:

```css
div{
  position:relative;
}
img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.marker{
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;height:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:red;
}
.marker:nth-child(2){
  left:21%;
  top:30%;
}
.marker:nth-child(3){
  left:58%;
  top:60%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xUBZg0y.png" />
  <span class="marker"></span>
  <span class="marker"></span>     
</div>
```